# How to rename Domain on a fresh install?

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2016

I want to rename a domain. It's on a fresh Windows Server install, and literally nothing has been done on it yet (aside from installing the OS and minimal configuration to make it a DC).

What do I need to do?

Normally I would delegate this task to someone with more experience in this area, but I need to set some other stuff up and don't want to wait. I'm a full stack developer but my knowledge of networking and DCs is minimal. So please answer with that context in mind :)

Comment: My recommendation, in this unique scenario, would be to wipe the disk and start again.  Renaming a domain is possible but complicated and potentially risky, there's no need to go to the trouble if there's no data needing to be kept.

Comment: You shouldn't need to wipe the disk. Demote the DC back to a regular server. Make sure it is not a member of any domain. Then promote it to DC, you will name the domain as part of the promotion process.

Comment: @Larryc Awesome... I knew there had to be a simple way to do this. Thanks!